# how to overlay a series of images in GPUImage

Tags: image, overlay, sequence, blend, gpuimage

I have been looking at GPUImage but cannot figure out how to overlay a series of png or jpg images on top of the video while I am displaying it and recording it.  I have roughly 150 photos in a sequence that I want to overlay (or multiply actually) on top of the video.  It seems like I should just be able to every 1/24th of a second swap out the texture from one frame to the next in the two image overlay or multiply filter.  I am not sure if that is going to even work though?

In a related question, if I make a custom filter based on the two input blend filters, would there be any way to change the *second* texture from a UIImage after instantiating the filter and starting off the camera capture?

Answer (score 0):

I actually did manage to get this to work albeit not in the way that I had originally intended but it works just as well.  What I had to do was use a GPUImageMovie object.

So the code looks like:

```
filter10 = [[GPUImageAddBlendFilter alloc] init];

[filter10 forceProcessingAtSize:_imageView7.sizeInPixels];

NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"sample_film" withExtension:@"mov"];

_imageMovie = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithURL:url];

_imageMovie.playAtActualSpeed = true;

_imageMovie.delegate = self;

[_imageMovie addTarget:filter10];

[_imageMovie startProcessing];

[filter10 addTarget:_imageView7];

[_videoCamera startCameraCapture];
```

Thanks to Brad Larson's GPUImage I am finally able to make the video app that I wanted to make with adequate performance and without having to rely on CIFilter's which did not have everything I needed.  I needed to write some custom filters for one thing.